# Moved server (centOS7) "Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly"

Tags: install

I previously ran Vesta CP on Ubuntu and wanted to run something a little faster so chose centOS7 minimal. Installed Vesta CP and restored my backup. All my sites are running fine. Except for the ones running Craft CMS.

**I would like to stress that the backup worked perfectly before**

I get the error "Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly"
Now I'v been (honestly) trying for the past 6 hours to fix this on my own but I can't figure it out.

PHP runs as adminBOB (determent using: )
And checking my chmod the user and group are adminBOB:adminBOB (same as if I make a new folder or upload a new file)

Apache/httpd runs as "apache:apache" changing the owner of all my files for this site doesn't make the error go away either.

I'm also my http.conf (and tried php.ini) configured to have:

> php_admin_flag safe_mode off
>
> php_admin_value open_basedir none

So I'm almost certain those two are not on.
Everything (folder/files) wise is the same. Same control panel (that installs all services)

I have no idea what to do next to try and get CraftCMS working again.
Please assist! Thank you!!

Comment: If I move my /craft/ folder (and adjust the index.php setting) Craft works. But I really want to have it outside of the public_html folder. So it's not a craft specific problem, but something else?

Comment: By chance do you have something like Suhosin or mod_security installed?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Just checked with phpinfo(); does not show mod_security nor Suhosin.

Comment: I'm no sysadmin, but what happens if you change PHP to run under the `apache:apache` user and group?

Comment: No worries. I did try that. "chown -R user:grouphere /home/kitsune/web/" (holds all my websites) where user:grouphere had any possible combination. PHP appears to be running as root (lsof -i | grep :http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out Vesta has a funny way of handing httpd config files.
There was another one tucked away somewhere where "open_basedir"
They are kept in "/home/admin(username)/conf/web/httpd.conf"

Removing that fixed it.

Such a pain, tooks me hours to figure out something so simple.
I had already removed it from the httpd.conf in the default location.

Something to keep in mind if anyone has the error and is running VESTA CP!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!